Question about differential signal routing
Would it be possible to know how we can calculate the distance that we must leave between two  the two signals of a differential pair
And from what speed can we have crosstalk between the differential pairs?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Yes, there is loads of information that you should find with a simple web search. Try this for starters:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snla187/snla187.pdf?ts=1715060339190

It depends what aspect you ask. Do you want to have a specific impedance, or just know rules of thumb how much distance to other wires you must leave.

A good starting point would be to use the differential pairs / XTALK calculator in Saturn PCB Design toolkit. Pick the differential signaling protocol from the list or enter custom specs if it's not there.

